# How to add detail view on the master view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, master-detail

I would like to put the detail view in the master i.e there will be only one dynamic view. When the user taps on a cell,the detail view will be displayed below the cell and the remaining cells will be pushed downwards.

Can I do something like this?

[image: This is the master view]

When the user taps on the cell 1,the detail view of the cell one gets displayed between the cell1 and cell2 like shown below.The cells 2,3 will be pushed downwards to display the data.

[image: detail view in master view]

Is this possible in iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some spare time today and wrote a complete example that expands and collaps. In the simple case, you can simply modify the hardcoded data, but you can load the structure during runtime as well. 
I put it on Github, it might be useful for others as well:
https://github.com/efalkenberg/ExpandableTableView

Answer (score 0):

With an array that indicates what type should be shown you can insert 3 cells dynamically like the following:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // old value = @[@0,@0];
    self.data = @[@0,@1,@1,@1,@0];

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSInteger i=indexPath.row; i< indexPath.row+3; i++)
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+1 inSection:0]];
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and will be called through the datasource protocol for the cells to be inserted.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if([self.data[indexPath.row]  isEqual: @0]){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"level1cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"level2cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    // Configure the cell...    
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

PS: i used the array with ones and zeros to make the code simple to read, you should definitely replace this with something more elegant :)

Comment: If I do this, the first cell will be replaced with the new 3 cells. I don't want my first cell to be removed. I want to add a view between two table cells that shows the detail view!!

Comment: if we tap again on the same cell,will the sub-cells add again?